# Alternate of with clause in query builder in laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I write a query using Eloquent in laravel 5 in which i use `with Clause` but when i write the query in laravel query Builder in which i cannot find any `with Clause` Please tell me the alternate of with Clause in query builder.

Here is my query in eloquent:

```
$invitedOnActivity = $this->isInvitedOnActivity($activity->id, $activity->user_id, $authUser->id);

        if($invitedOnActivity == true && $activity->activity_privacy == 'invite_only'){

            if($activity->activity_privacy_visible == 0)
                {
                    $activity = Activity::where('id', $activity->id)->with(['joins' => function($query) use ($userFriendIds) {
                        $query->whereIn('user_id', $userFriendIds);
                    }])->withCount(['joins' => function ($query) use ($userFriendIds) {
                        $query->whereIn('user_id', $userFriendIds);
                    }])->first();
                        // return response()->json(['q'=>$activity],200);
                } 
                else if ($activity->activity_privacy_visible == 1 && in_array($activity->user_id, $userFriendIds))
                {
                    $activity = Activity::where('id', $activity->id)->where('activity_privacy_visible', 1)->with(['joins' => function($query) use ($userFriendIds) {
                        $query->whereIn('user_id', $userFriendIds);
                    }])->withCount(['joins' => function ($query) use ($userFriendIds){
                        $query->whereIn('user_id', $userFriendIds);
                    }])->first();
                        // return response()->json(['w'=>$activity],200);      
                } 
                else {
                    continue;
                }
        }
```

i want this query to change in query builder. Here is the query i will tried but i think its not work.

```
if($invitedOnActivity == false){
            $activity = DB::table('activities')
                ->where('id', $activity->id)
                ->where('activity_privacy', 'invite_only')
                ->where('activity_privacy_visible', 0)
                ->get();
        }
```

In this query i could not find alternate of with clause. Please Help Me. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It's not possible. `with` clause uses relation definition of eloquent models. You can only use `joins` in this case.

Comment: How to use Joins ? @maximkou

Comment: @maximkou Please help?